# Typescript - how can a exclude a type from a generic type without using Exclude<>?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have a function that stores different values into the local storage by stringifying them and I want to limit the function from being able to work with Moment objects. The syntax would be this:

```
public static set<TValue>(
       key: LocalStorageKeyEnum,
       value: TValue,
       ...keySuffixes: string[]
   ) {
       localStorage.setItem(
           LocalStorage.buildKey(key, keySuffixes),
           JSON.stringify(value)
       )
   }
```

The thing is the function would work without any issues if the second argument would be a Moment object and I want to exclude this type when writing `<TValue>`. Is there a way to do this using Typescript or the only way to go is running a check on run-time? I could work with 2 types, where the second would be a type that excludes the property of type Moment, like so

```
type Variants = {
   value: TValue,
   date: moment.Moment
}

type ExcludeDate = Exclude {typeof Variants, "date"}
```

but I was wondering if there's another way to do it. Thank you! I am new to Typescript so I am sorry if I wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude type by conditional type:

```
type MomentType = { x: string } // just an example simulation of moment

function set<TValue>(
       key: string,
       value: TValue extends MomentType ? never : TValue, // pay attention here
       ...keySuffixes: string[]
   ) {
       // implementation
}

set('key', { x: 'a' }) // error as its the MomentType
set('key', { y: 'a' }) // ok as its not the MomentType
```

The key line is `value: TValue extends MomentType ? never : TValue`. We say that if passed type extends our `MomentType` then the value is of the type `never`, what means you cannot pass value to it, as never is empty type (there is no instance of never).

`MomentType` was used only for example purposes, it can be any other type you want to exclude.